# How do I update an array of objects in component state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to update the property of an object which is stored in an array.

my state looks something like this:

```
state = {
  todos: [
    {
     id: '1',
     title: 'first item,
     completed: false
    },
    {
     id: '2',
     title: 'second item,
     completed: false
    }
  ],
}
```

What I am trying to do is access the second element in the 'todos' array and update the completed property to either false -> true or true -> false.

I have a button with the handler for update, and my class method for the update looks like this:

```
onUpdate = (id) => {
  const { todos } = this.state;
  let i = todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id);
  let status = todos[i].completed
  let updatedTodo = {
    ...todos[i],
    completed: !status
  }
  this.setState({
    todos: [
      ...todos.slice(0, i),
      updatedTodo,
      ...todos.slice(i + 1)
    ]
  });
}
```

While this does work, I want to find out if there is a more concise way of achieving the same result; I tried to use Object.assign(), but that didn't work out because my 'todos' is an array, not an object. Please enlighten me with better code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use [update function](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) to make sure you don't work on outdated data:

```
onUpdate = (id) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const copy = [...prevState.todos];
    const index = copy.findIndex(t => t.id === id);
    copy[index].completed = !copy[index].completed;

    return { todos: copy }
  })  
}
```

Comment: just tried this and it works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy your `todos` from `state`, then make edits, and after that put it back to the `state`

```
onUpdate = (id) => {
    var todos = [...this.state.todos]
    var target = todos.find(todo => todo.id == id)
    if (target) {
        target.completed = !target.completed
        this.setState({ todos })
    }
}
```